# Spring-WS Wss4jSecurityInterceptor doesn't decrypt received message

Tags: spring, cxf, spring-ws, ws-security

My case is as follows:

1. I wrote SOAP service using CXF
2. I wrote two SOAP clients - one using CXF and another using Spring-WS
3. I set up WSSecurity : "Timestamp Signature Encrypt" action on both sides (client / server)
4. CXF client works like charm, but Spring-WS cant decrypt response.

Server side is OK while interacting with CXF-client and Spring-client (it is properely decrypting, verifing signature, processing requests, sign, encrypt and finnaly send response).

Code:

CXF client:

---

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<bean id="inbound-logging" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
<bean id="outbound-logging" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />

<jaxws:client id="helloClient" serviceClass="com.example.HelloWorld"
    address="http://localhost:8282/HelloWorld">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="inbound-logging" />
        <ref bean="inbound-security" />
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="outbound-logging" />
        <ref bean="outbound-security" />
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>

<bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor" id="outbound-security">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature Encrypt"/>
            <entry key="user" value="client"/>              
            <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="config/client-crypto.properties"/>
            <entry key="encryptionPropFile" value="config/client-crypto.properties"/>
            <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
            <entry key="encryptionUser" value="server"/>
            <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="org.mydomain.ClientPasswordCallback"/>
            <entry key="signatureParts" value="{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"/>
            <entry key="encryptionParts" value="{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature;{Content}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"/>
            <entry key="encryptionSymAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor" id="inbound-security">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature Encrypt"/>
            <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="config/client-crypto.properties"/>
            <entry key="decryptionPropFile" value="config/client-crypto.properties"/>
            <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="org.mydomain.CustomPasswordCallback"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

---

Spring-WS client - wss-interceptor :

---

```
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wssInterceptor(
        @Qualifier("cryptoFactoryBean") CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean,
        @Qualifier("signValidCryptoFactoryBean") CryptoFactoryBean signValidCryptoFactoryBean) throws Exception {

    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();

    // outgoing securement

    interceptor.setSecurementUsername("client");
    interceptor.setSecurementPassword("123456");
    interceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");
    interceptor.setSecurementActions("Timestamp Signature Encrypt");

    interceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(cryptoFactoryBean.getObject());
    interceptor.setSecurementSignatureParts(
            "{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;" +
            "{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"
    );

    interceptor.setSecurementEncryptionCrypto(cryptoFactoryBean.getObject());
    interceptor.setSecurementEncryptionUser("server");
    interceptor.setSecurementEncryptionSymAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc");
    interceptor.setSecurementEncryptionParts(
            "{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature;" +
            "{Content}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"
    );

    // incoming validation:

    interceptor.setValidationActions("Timestamp Signature Encrypt");
    interceptor.setValidationDecryptionCrypto(cryptoFactoryBean.getObject());
    interceptor.setValidationSignatureCrypto(signValidCryptoFactoryBean.getObject());

    return interceptor;
}
```

---

Logging level is set to debug. Here is the result:

---

(... - logs related with encrypting data befrore send )
2015-08-09 19:09:45.181 DEBUG WSSecEncrypt:258 - Encryption complete.
2015-08-09 19:09:45.182 DEBUG sent:620 - Sent request [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData]
2015-08-09 19:09:45.223 DEBUG received:678 - Received response [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData] for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData]
2015-08-09 19:09:45.224 DEBUG Wss4jSecurityInterceptor:562 - **Validating message [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData] with actions [Timestamp Signature Encrypt]**
2015-08-09 19:09:45.225 DEBUG WSSecurityEngine:236 - enter processSecurityHeader()
2015-08-09 19:09:45.229 WARN  Wss4jSecurityInterceptor:281 - **Could not validate request: No WS-Security header found**
2015-08-09 19:09:45.229 DEBUG Wss4jSecurityInterceptor:288 - No exception resolver present, creating basic soap fault
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault"). Expected elements are <{}helloRequest>,<{http://example.com}helloResponse>
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:809)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:730)
    at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.unmarshal(MarshallingUtils.java:62)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$3.extractData(WebServiceTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:596)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:384)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:374)
    at client.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault"). Expected elements are <{}helloRequest>,<{http://example.com}helloResponse>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:229)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:354)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:337)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:127)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:726)
    ... 12 more

---

It looks like Spring is trying to process response without decrypting it earlier.

---

I've found solution to the problem. I didn't set password callback, so wss4j-interceptor couldn't decrypt response. Here is code that fix the issue:

```
KeyStoreCallbackHandler keyStoreCallbackHandler = new KeyStoreCallbackHandler();
keyStoreCallbackHandler.setPrivateKeyPassword("123456");
interceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(keyStoreCallbackHandler);
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Where should I add this snippet? In CallbackHandler or need to create new class and add it in the cfg file? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeyStoreCallbackHandler wasn't defined for the interceptor - that was the case. Appropriate code in the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a soap fault from the other party. Soap fault messages are not encrypted this is why **Wss4jSecurityInterceptor** is complaining about the ws-security header.

```
2015-08-09 19:09:45.229 WARN  Wss4jSecurityInterceptor:281 - 
**Could not validate request: No WS-Security header found**
```

It seems also that the processing of the message continue while it should normaly stops. The JAXB marshaller complains that **(uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault")** is not from the context.

```
2015-08-09 19:09:45.229 DEBUG Wss4jSecurityInterceptor:288 - 
No exception resolver present, creating basic soap fault
Exception in thread "main"
 org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: 
JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
 (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault"). 
Expected elements are <{}helloRequest>,<{http://example.com}helloResponse>
```

I would recommend the following:

1. Log the soap fault to determine what the other party needs
2. Whenever you receive a soap fault, you should stop processing the request